# 'SXSSFWorkbook.setCompressTempFiles(true)' does not work on my local (runs on Windows)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Although setting `setCompressTempFiles(true)` of my **SXSSFWorkbook**, it does not compress files which are saved on my local temp file. For Excel file that has 250.000 rows, it creates ~190MB temp file. I delete `setCompressTempFiles(true)` line to not compress, but it still generates ~190MB temp files for the same Excel file that has 250.000 rows.

I could not find any issue about this problem on Google.

Is there anybody faced with the same issue?

Version:

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.10-FINAL</version>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache POI are you using, and if it isn't the most recent, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr, question updated. Compressing spesification comes with "Version 3.8-beta5 (2011-12-17)" https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51961

Comment: Is it still the same with the latest version 3.13 or 3.14-beta1?

Comment: I test it with POI 3.13 and I could not find the temp files,named "poi-sxssf-sheet", in default temporary files directory on windows, although doc says " temp files are created in the default temporary-file directory with a prefix "poi-sxssf-sheet" ". Reference: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SheetDataWriter.html#createTempFile() . So I could not see the exact result of my test. (Note: workBook.dispose() is not called!)

Comment: Does SXSSFWorkbook used compress files at all?